# auto slidedown div not working when page fully loads

Tags: javascript, html, slide

i want to make so when the page full loads the div content slides down once but not working here is code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#slidercontent').delay(1000).slideDown(100);
});
```

no result ;( hot to fix it ?

html

```
<div id="slidercontent">(here goes my Slideshow)</div>
```

css

```
#slidercontent {width:1101px; height:195px; margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: show some html too or add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `display:none;` in the CSS. Also I hope that you are including the jQuery library before your javascript:

**Here's the working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/Sjarv/1/

(have increased the slideDown time to 1000 to make it more visible)

Answer (score -1):

There is no default effect named slideLeft so you have to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selector").delay(1000).animate({width:0},500);
});
```

or you can use **setTimeout()** method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#slidercontent').animate({width:0},100,function(){
            // do some other stuff after the animation is complete
        });
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: Which is the error you have? You can use firebug to see javascript errors

Comment: I checked right now on jQuery documentation and there seems that slideLeft is not an default effect, so you have to use animate. I've edited the answer and that should work :)

Comment: he wants to use slideDown not slideLeft & there is a function slideDown!

Comment: the problem is not on slideshow its on this div why its not sliding down even its empty WHY

Comment: He changed the code.. the first time he wanted to use slideLeft.. so sorry for my "incorrect" answer